# MongoDB Replica Set Upgrade

Tags: mongodb

I am upgrading my MongoDB replica set from 3.0.15 to 3.2.22. And when I start up a node with the 3.2.22 binaries, I keep seeing the below for `lastHeartbeatMessage` whenever I run `rs.status()`

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGN7f.png)

I see this message even though that node is showing up as `SECONDARY` and there is nothing in the log files that say that something is wrong. And whenever I insert a new document into the `PRIMARY`, I can see the same document in the `SECONDARY` as well and the above message then disappears. Is there a reason why I am seeing the above message to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue affecting MongoDB 3.2 ([SERVER-20144](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20144)) where a stale `lastHeartbeatMessage` may not be cleared until new data is replicated from the primary. Inserting or updating data should resolve this.

I believe this has been mitigated by replication changes in MongoDB 3.4, which performs periodic no-op writes if a cluster is idle for more than 10 seconds (per [SERVER-23892](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23892)). The 3.4 no-op replication change was part of the [spec for Max Staleness](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/max-staleness/max-staleness.rst#primary-must-write-periodic-no-ops) which allows drivers to estimate the staleness of secondaries in order to support a new [`maxStalenessSeconds` read preference option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#maxstalenessseconds).

Since the MongoDB 3.2 release series reached end of life in September, 2018 I would strongly recommend upgrading to a newer and actively supported production release.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's what I figured, that it was not anything serious, but I just wanted to confirm that either way. I do plan on migrating up to 4.0 but I just had to do the upgrades in steps.